# how to upload java application Jar or artifacts file into nexus server bin repo using github action workflow?

Tags: github-actions, nexus, cicd

how to upload java application Jar or artifacts file into nexus server bin repo using GitHub action workflow?

my GitHub action runner is self hosted agent which have permission to access the nexus bin repo folder.

what code should I refer in GitHub action  workflow.